# Citation of the general form of the first mean value theorem for integrals

Tags: calculus

In this link [First mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals), there is a **general** form of the MVT:

``In general, if $f$ : $[a, b]$ → $R$ is continuous and $g$ is an integrable function that does not change sign on $[a, b]$, then there exists $c$ in $(a, b)$ such that $\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx=f(c)\int_a^bg(x)dx$.''

I need a citation in my paper of this general form result. But I failed to find one after search the google scholar for 1 hour.. Any help? Thanks.

Note, the citation used in the link ``Michael Comenetz (2002). Calculus: The Elements. World Scientific'' is not presenting the thereom in that general form.

Comment: You can also cite Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's _Table of Integrals_. It's on page 249 of the 8th edition (an earlier one will also have it, I guess).

Comment: Great! I found it on the p247 in the 7th edition.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can search it on "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" of Rudin Walter.

I don't know exactly the page but I will look for it.

Comment: Look between the pages 106-109

Comment: thanks. I am looking at the [3rd edition](https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf). It is the generalised MVT but it is not for integrals...